# Is good idea to convert UUID to BIGINT in Postgres 9 to have global IDs generated in distributed clients?

Tags: database, postgresql, uuid, uniqueidentifier, biginteger

I will have several distributed clients that mirror some tables in a centralized postgres 9 database. The system will work as 2-way sync of data. The clients could be offline for several hours and days in worst case scenario (are mobile clients for collect data in the field)

So, I need to do inserts in the clients and generate a global ID for them. Currently I have a GUID field for that, but casually looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html discover a GUID can be converted to-from a INT64 or BIGINT.

So I wonder if is fine to generate a GUID in the client, convert it to BIGINT and use it as the primary key in the database (because is faster/cheaper to join and search by INTs than GUIDs or chars)

Comment: I don't think you can convert (without loss) to 64-bits, only 128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squishing a GUID into a 64-bit INT64 or BIGINT sounds like a bad idea, since an UUID is 128 bits long.

Also, the database does not store a GUID/UUID as a string, it stores it as a 128 bit number which is a fairly optimal and easily indexed format.

Comment: Your are correct. I misread the python doc and asume the 128bit number was equal in size to BIGINT in postgres. Is possible to have a global ID with bigint calculate in the client?

Comment: @mamcx A Python long integer would work, although you could also use Python's [uuid type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html). It seems to also have all required functionality for converting between UUID and integer formats.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson -- just a random thought: while Postgres supports UUID natively, MySQL doesn't, how about converting the UUID into two BIGINTs for MySQL?